# Problems with if-else statement on related dropdown elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, this, display

I am creating a series of drop-down elements, with an initially visible question and an answer that is toggled between `display: block` and `display: none` upon clicking the question. Clicking each question for its answer also causes all the other answers to become `display: none`.

The problem I'm having is to do with the if-else statement following on from when a `.question` is clicked, hide all answers that don't relate to this question. If the next answer is `display: none`, change it to `display: block`.

This next if-else statement should instruct: if the next answer is `display: block`, then change it back to `display: none`. However, while I am receiving no console errors, the if-else statement does not run at all as currently stands.

Hopefully this is another case of me being a bit thick while reading the code!

```js
function script() {
  $('.question').on('click', function() {
    $('#faqs').find('.answer').not($(this)).hide();
    if ($(this).next(".answer").css("display", "none")) {
      $(this).next(".answer").css("display", "block");
    } else if ($(this).next(".answer").css("display", "block")) {
      $(this).next(".answer").css("display", "none");
    };
  });
}

$(document).ready(script);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="faqs">
  <div class="qna">
    <div class="question">
      <h8>
        Question 1
      </h8>
    </div>
    <div class="answer" style="display: none">
      <p>
        Answer 1
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="qna">
    <div class="question">
      <h8>
        Question 2
      </h8>
    </div>
    <div class="answer" style="display: none">
      <p>
        Answer 2
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="qna">
    <div class="question">
      <h8>
        Question 3
      </h8>
    </div>
    <div class="answer" style="display: none">
      <p>
        Answer 3
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of issues in your logic. Firstly, your `if` statement condition uses the *setter* of `css()`, not the *getter*. As such it will always return `true` as it coerces the jQuery object returned to a boolean.

Secondly, you hide all the `.answer` elements before you perform the logic, hence even when corrected, the `if` condition will always see that the `.answer` is `display: none` as you just hid it.

Thirdly, You provide `$(this)` to `not()`, yet `this` is a reference to the `.question`, not the `.answer`. With those issues addressed, this works:

```js
function script() {
  $('.question').on('click', function() {       
    var $answer = $(this).next('.answer');
    if ($answer.css("display") == "none") {
      $answer.css("display", "block");
    } else {
      $answer.css("display", "none");
    };
    
    $('#faqs').find('.answer').not($answer).hide();
  });
}

$(document).ready(script);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="faqs">
  <div class="qna">
    <div class="question">
      <h8>
        Question 1
      </h8>
    </div>
    <div class="answer" style="display: none">
      <p>
        Answer 1
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="qna">
    <div class="question">
      <h8>
        Question 2
      </h8>
    </div>
    <div class="answer" style="display: none">
      <p>
        Answer 2
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="qna">
    <div class="question">
      <h8>
        Question 3
      </h8>
    </div>
    <div class="answer" style="display: none">
      <p>
        Answer 3
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note the use of the `$answer` variable in the above to increase performance by reducing the number of times you access the DOM.

You should note however, that this all can be made much simpler. You can use `toggle()` to just hide/show the relevant `.answer` on successive clicks. Try this:

```js
function script() {
  $('.question').on('click', function() {
    var $answer = $(this).next('.answer').toggle();
    $('#faqs').find('.answer').not($answer).hide();
  });
}

$(document).ready(script);
```

```css
.answer {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="faqs">
  <div class="qna">
    <div class="question">
      <h8>
        Question 1
      </h8>
    </div>
    <div class="answer">
      <p>
        Answer 1
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="qna">
    <div class="question">
      <h8>
        Question 2
      </h8>
    </div>
    <div class="answer">
      <p>
        Answer 2
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="qna">
    <div class="question">
      <h8>
        Question 3
      </h8>
    </div>
    <div class="answer">
      <p>
        Answer 3
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you! I'd attempted solutions involving toggle() and hide()/show(), but having kept running into the same problem I ended up trying to be verrry verrry explicit by using the display properties - to no avail. The real example I'm working on also has a couple of other elements that toggle in and out at the same time, but i should be able to cross-apply the logic used here. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

it seems you are using Jquery, so it's better to use `$('.answer').show()` or `$('.answer').hide()`. Also, display: none will be applied to all the classes that's why on click of each question it is hiding all the answers. Its better to iterate over loop and dynamically assign classes like - answer-1, answer-2